# Memory efficient way of implementing bootstrap in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataset loaded into memory and would like to bootstrap from it. Currently I use sklearn `resample` default implementation. I use a generator to yield a bootstrap batch from the dataset residing in memory.

However, this is incredibly memory heavy, as every bootstrap iteration creates a new array.   Is there a more efficient way to implement the bootstrap either from data stored on disk, or in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create indices which will slice your original features and targets and apply those every time you need a bootrstrapped dataset.

Here is an example implementation using sklearn's boston dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston


def get_bootstrap_indices(dataset, datasets: int):
    for _ in range(datasets):
        yield np.random.choice(np.arange(len(dataset)), size=len(dataset), replace=True)


dataset = load_boston().data
print(f"Original dataset shape: {dataset.shape}")

for indices in get_bootstrap_indices(dataset, 10):
    print(dataset[indices].shape)
```

Comment: Will this not yield a copy? Especially if I need the indices to be sampled with replacement, would I not have to create a new object with those slices?

Comment: Added an example, no, it will not yield a copy, it will yield a view of dataset. Is that fine for you?

Comment: thank you, I’ll try a similar implementation, except my data is in numpy arrays.

Comment: This data is contained in numpy arrays as well.

Comment: thank you, I assumed it was a DataFrame. . I’ll attempt similar

Comment: This is not true, indexing via an array of indices is the so called advanced indexing, which always yields a copy
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing